# ERROR Subquery returns more than 1 row on UPDATE query

Tags: sql, derby

I have made some succsesfully updates on some tables of my DB, but there is a one that throws the "Subquery returns more than 1 row" error.

The query is this:

```
update detallesfacturas set cantidad = 3 where iddetalle = 725;
```

note: I use APACHE Derby as Data Base engine.

can anyone please help me.

thanks before hand!

Comment: There is nothing intrinsically wrong with your update statement. It also doesn't have a subquery. Do you have a trigger on that table? I suspect that is where your error is actually being thrown from

Comment: is your **iddetalle** the primary key? If isn't, you probably have more than one item with iddetalle = 725

Comment: ooohhhhh, yes, LordBaconPants it's the trigger. I am testing the trigger but did not think the error is on it.  Edilson Borges, yes iddetalles is my primary key. thanks guys. I'll check my trigger. :)

Comment: Feel free update your question with it if you want more eyes on it

Comment: where is your subquery?